# TCL / Write a tabulated list to a file

Tags: tcl

I have a variable, let's say `xx`, with a list of index 0 and index 1 values. I want to modify a script (not mine) which previously defines a function, `pptable`, i.e.,

```
proc pptable {l1 l2} {
    foreach i1 $l1 i2 $l2 {
        puts " [format %6.2f $i1]\t[format %6.2f $i2]"
    }
}
```

so that it displays the output into two columns using

```
pptable [lindex $xx 1] [lindex $xx 0]
```

However, I want to write the output directly to a file. Could you tell me how I can send the data to a file instead to the display?

Comment: Does not answer your question, but you don't need 2 format commands: `puts [format {%6.2f\t%6.2f} $i1 $i2]`

Answer (score 2):

One of the neatest ways of doing this is to [stack](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M32) on a [channel transform](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/transchan.htm) that redirects `stdout` to where you want it to go. This works *even if the write to `stdout` happens from C code or in a different thread* as it plugs into the channel machinery. The code is a little bit long (and requires Tcl 8.6) but is reliable and actually mostly very simple.

```
package require Tcl 8.6;  # *REQUIRED* for [chan push] and [chan pop]

proc RedirectorCallback {targetHandle op args} {
    # The switch/lassign pattern is simplest way of doing this in one procedure
    switch $op {
        initialize {
            lassign $args handle mode
            # Sanity check
            if {$mode ne "write"} {
                close $targetHandle
                error "this is just a write transform"
            }
            # List of supported subcommands
            return {initialize finalize write}
        }
        finalize {
            lassign $args handle
            # All we need to do here is close the target file handle
            close $targetHandle
        }
        write {
            lassign $args handle buffer
            # Write the data to *real* destination; this does the redirect
            puts -nonewline $targetHandle $buffer
            # Stop the data going to *true* stdout by returning empty string
            return ""
            # If we returned the data instead, this would do a 'tee'
        }
        default {
            error "unsupported subcommand"
        }
    }
}

# Here's a wrapper to make the transform easy to use
proc redirectStdout {file script} {
    # Stack the transform onto stdout with the file handle to write to
    # (which is going to be $targetHandle in [redirector])
    chan push stdout [list RedirectorCallback [open $file "wb"]]

    # Run the script and *definitely* pop the transform after it finishes
    try {
        uplevel 1 $script
    } finally {
        chan pop stdout
    }
}
```

How would we actually use this? It's really very easy in practice:

```
# Exactly the code you started with
proc pptable {l1 l2} {
    foreach i1 $l1 i2 $l2 {
        puts " [format %6.2f $i1]\t[format %6.2f $i2]"
    }
}

# Demonstrate that stdout is working as normal
puts "before"

# Our wrapped call that we're capturing the output from; pick your own filename!
redirectStdout "foo.txt" {
    pptable {1.2 1.3 1.4} {6.9 6.8 6.7}
}

# Demonstrate that stdout is working as normal again
puts "after"
```

When I run that code, I get this:

```
bash$ tclsh8.6 stdout-redirect-example.tcl 
before
after
bash$ cat foo.txt 
   1.20   6.90
   1.30   6.80
   1.40   6.70
```

I believe that's precisely what you are looking for.

---

You can do this with less code if you use [Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_core/transformcore.html) and TclOO to help deal with the machinery:

```
package require Tcl 8.6
package require tcl::transform::core

oo::class create WriteRedirector {
    superclass tcl::transform::core

    variable targetHandle
    constructor {targetFile} {
        set targetHandle [open $targetFile "wb"]
    }
    destructor {
        close $targetHandle
    }

    method write {handle buffer} {
        puts -nonewline $targetHandle $buffer
        return ""
    }

    # This is the wrapper, as a class method
    self method redirectDuring {channel targetFile script} {
        chan push $channel [my new $targetFile]
        try {
            uplevel 1 $script
        } finally {
            chan pop $channel
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
proc pptable {l1 l2} {
    foreach i1 $l1 i2 $l2 {
        puts " [format %6.2f $i1]\t[format %6.2f $i2]"
    }
}

puts "before"
WriteRedirector redirectDuring stdout "foo.txt" {
    pptable {1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5} {6.9 6.8 6.7 6.6}
}
puts "after"
```

Comment: Note that the code intercepts `stdout` at the byte level and needs no further encoding transformation or end-of-line processing; that's why the text file is opened in `wb` mode and the internal puts uses `-nonewline`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want or can't modify the existing script and proc `pptable`, correct?

If so, there are different options, depending on your exact situation:

- Redirect `stdout`: `tclsh yourscript.tcl > your.out`
- Redefine `puts` (for a clearly defined scope):

  ```
  rename ::puts ::puts.orig 
  proc puts args { 
      set fh [open your.out w]; 
      ::puts.orig $fh $args; 
      close $fh
  }
  # run pptable, source the script
  ```

  This theme has been covered before, e.g., [tcl stop all output going to stdout channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307898/tcl-stop-all-output-going-to-stdout-channel)
- Rewire Tcl's `stdout` channel (not necessarily recommended):

  ```
  close stdout
  open your.out w
  # run pptable, source the script
  ```

  This has also been elaborated on before, e.g. [Tracing stdout and stderr in Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210068/tracing-stdout-and-stderr-in-tcl)